# Disable Column in VA01

Tags: abap, sap-erp, dynpro

I have a requirement where I need to disable the full column in Sales Order Line item. Fields are **VBAP-ARKTX** and **VBAP-KDMAT**.

I've found the way to disable columns with data in them, but not the whole column.

I used **USEREXIT_FIELD_MODIFICATION** to achieve this using the following code;

```
IF sy-TCODE = 'VA02'.
  IF screen-name = 'VBAP-KDMAT' .
      screen-INPUT = 0.
      modify screen.
  ENDIF.
ENDIF.
```

Is there a way to disable the whole column?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific problem I faced was how to disable two fields, but let standard mapped data to be displayed in them.

To cater this requirement I used the following;

Include: MV45AFZZ
User Exit Name: USEREXIT_FIELD_MODIFICATION
Enhancement Name: -Any name you want-

I created an Enhancement and wrote the following code;

```
"Specify the condition
IF VBAK-VKORG = '1234' AND ( sy-TCODE = 'VA02' OR sy-TCODE = 'VA01' ) AND ( screen-name = 'VBAP-KDMAT' OR screen-name = 'VBAP-ARKTX' ).

        screen-input = 0."disable input
        MODIFY SCREEN.

         DATA: i_tab_mara TYPE TABLE OF MARA WITH HEADER LINE.
         DATA: l_maktx TYPE MAKT-MAKTX.
         DATA: WA_MARA LIKE LINE OF i_tab_mara.

         DATA: i_tab_vbap TYPE TABLE OF VBAP WITH HEADER LINE.
         DATA: wa_vbap LIKE LINE OF i_tab_vbap.

          IF sy-TCODE = 'VA01' .

             SELECT SINGLE * from MARA INTO WA_MARA WHERE MATNR eq VBAP-MATNR.

             SELECT MAKTX FROM MAKT INTO l_maktx WHERE MATNR eq VBAP-MATNR.
             ENDSELECT.

             VBAP-KDMAT = WA_MARA-KDMAT.
             VBAP-ARKTX = l_maktx.

             MODIFY SCREEN.

          ELSEIF sy-TCODE = 'VA02' .

           SELECT SINGLE * FROM VBAP INTO WA_VBAP WHERE VBELN eq VBAK-VBELN AND POSNR eq VBAP-POSNR.

           IF WA_VBAP-ARKTX eq ''." Check if the fileds are empty, otherwise old data is overwritten

             SELECT MAKTX FROM MAKT INTO l_maktx WHERE MATNR eq VBAP-MATNR.
             ENDSELECT.

             VBAP-ARKTX = l_maktx.

             MODIFY SCREEN.

           ENDIF.

           IF WA_VBAP-KDMAT eq ''." Check if the fileds are empty, otherwise old data is overwritten

             SELECT SINGLE * from MARA INTO WA_MARA WHERE MATNR eq VBAP-MATNR.

             VBAP-KDMAT = WA_MARA-KDMAT.

             MODIFY SCREEN.

           ENDIF.
    ENDIF.
ENDIF.
```

Answer (score 2):

[Adjusting table control](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw73ehp1/7.31.19/en-US/fb/ac5f4261ae11d295b10000e82de14a/content.htm?no_cache=true) which contains items is the easiest and the most recommended way. It can be done for single user or for group of users.
Otherwise, try to create a [screen variant](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70ehp1/helpdata/en/7d/f63a10015111d396480000e82de14a/content.htm) in SHD0. It allows easily hide any column of any table and any field on the screen.

Answer (score -1):

There is one thing, that You can do in the dynpro-designer. There You can modify the sap-standard-dynpro as a dynpro-modification.
Nevertheless, this might be overwritten with the next release. Is this also an option for You ?